# Draw Highcharts dynamically by data from web service and add new points periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I want to draw a highchart line chart with data from webservice that called by ajax.

First i want to initialize my chart with new data received from ajax call.

Chart could have many series (without any limit in cuont).

My purpose is to **first initialize** my chart with new data from ajax call 
and after drawing new chart my **ajax function called peridically every 2 second**s and **if new data contains point received from webservice , dynamically add to chart**

This is my html container :

```
<div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my script :

```
<script>

    var sensor_name;
    var my_chart;
    var chart_options = new Object();
    var FLAG_INITIALIZATION_DONE = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
        drawChart();
    });

    function drawChart() {

        chart_options.chart = new Object();
        chart_options.chart.type = "spline";
        chart_options.chart.animation = Highcharts.svg;
        chart_options.chart.marginRight = 10;
        chart_options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        chart_options.chart.events = new Object();
        chart_options.chart.ignoreHiddenSeries = false;

        chart_options.chart.events.load = loadChartData();

        chart_options.title = new Object();
        chart_options.title.text = "";

        chart_options.xAxis = new Object();
        chart_options.xAxis.type = 'datetime';
        chart_options.xAxis.tickPixelInterval = 150;

        chart_options.yAxis = new Object();
        chart_options.yAxis.title = new Object();
        chart_options.yAxis.title.text = "sensor";

        chart_options.tooltip = new Object();
        chart_options.tooltip.formatter = function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        };

        chart_options.legend = new Object();
        chart_options.legend.enabled = false;

        chart_options.exporting = new Object();
        chart_options.exporting.enabled = true;

        chart_options.series = new Array();

        my_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_options);

    }

    function loadChartData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/luci/test2.php',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var chart_data = response.chart_data;
                if (FLAG_INITIALIZATION_DONE == 0) {
                    FLAG_INITIALIZATION_DONE = 1;
                    my_chart.setTitle({text: response.sensor_name});
                    $.each(chart_data, function (key, value) {
                        var curr = [];
                        curr.push(value.data[0]);
                        curr.push(value.data[1]);
                        console.log(curr);
                        my_chart.addSeries({
                            name: value.name,
                            data: curr
                        }, false);
                    });
                } else {
                    $.each(chart_data, function (key, value) {
                        my_chart.series[key].addPoint([value.data[0], value.data[1]], true, true);
                    });
                }

                setTimeout(loadChartData, 4000);

            }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                console.log("error");

            }, complete: function (xhr, status) {

                console.log("complete");

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

And the data that received from ajax call is like this :

```
{"sensor_name":"Temperature","chart_data":[{"name":"MSDM0","data":[1475605462,8]},{"name":"MSDM1","data":[1475605462,20]},{"name":"MSDM2","data":[1475605462,63]},{"name":"MSDM3","data":[1475605462,6]},{"name":"MSDM4","data":[1475605462,88]}]}
```

Comment: "i want" your test code :)

Comment: i updated my question @WhiteLine

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Are you able to initialize your chart?

Comment: after some testing now i think first i should initialize my chart with some points (a new series) and then add new points to that @GrzegorzBlachliński

Comment: Not necessary, but I think that you should have your series object with data array (event if this array will be empty)